# Which weapon has the highest potential for petrification?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

Can somebody please tell me what weapon in Kid Icarus: Uprising has the highest potential of petrification? Also, could anyone let me know if Air Battle petrification makes foes plummet down to the ground? I have a Midnight Palm on 3, a Flintlock Staff and End-All Arm on 1, and a Cutter Palm on 4. If I have others, I didn't study every single one of my weapons. Does anybody have any suggestions? By the way, most status shows in Air Battles, such as burn and poison.

Answer (score 2):

There is no weapon that has a natural, no-modifiers-needed chance of petrification (or at least, none is mentioned in [this list](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Status_Ailments)). Any weapon that has a petrification modifier is equal to any other weapon that has a modifier of the same strength; however, it's kind of unknown exactly how the effect is applied, so certain kinds of weapons may be more favourable:

- If the effect is applied after a certain amount of damage is dealt, then weapons that deal more damage will be more favourable.
- If the effect is applied as a percentage chance per hit, or after a certain number of attacks hit, then rapid-firing weapons are more favourable.

As far as I know, status effects do not appear in air battles, so petrifying enemies would be impossible.

Comment: I think poison and burning can be applied in air battles, but you're definitely right that petrification can't. It might also help to note that a charged shot has a much higher chance to inflict a condition than a single continuous fire shot.